# Pandas: index data by a histogram result

Tags: python, statistics, pandas

I'm trying to index data by their probability (estimated with a simple histogram). The objective is to select items in the series with a probability less then some threshold.

I have a series of integer values, for example:

```
import pandas as pnd
import numpy  as np

series = pnd.Series(np.random.poisson(5, size = 100))
```

then I calculate their histogram like this:

```
tmp  = {"series" : series, "count" : np.ones(len(series))}
hist = pnd.DataFrame(tmp).groupby("series").sum()
freq = hist / hist.sum()
```

So now I have the frequencies of each result indexed by the result, and the series of results. I have now two questions:

- Is there a way to index `series` by the mapping of result/frequency defined by `freq`?
- If I manage to do this, how do I select only results with frequency greater than some value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `map` Series method:

```
In [16]: series.map(freq['count'])
Out[16]: 
0     0.12
1     0.06
2     0.20
3     0.11
4     0.02
5     0.13
6     0.14
7     0.11
8     0.12
9     0.16
10    0.20
<snip>
```

you can then do:

```
In [22]: series[series.map(freq['count']) > 0.16]
Out[22]: 
2     4
10    4
11    4
22    4
27    4
31    4
34    4
56    4
64    4
71    4
73    4
76    4
77    4
79    4
80    4
86    4
88    4
89    4
91    4
99    4
```